# Обработка ответа от api и обновление данных в массиве

Tags: javascript, vue.js, api

Работаю с vue и api. Получил я массив объектов

```
let data = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
];
```

Каждый объект - строка из БД. Всё там как обычно: id и другие поля. Отображаю на странице.

После я обновляю данные одного из этих объектов через пользовательский интерфейс. Отправляю изменённый объект на сервер. И в ответ получаю этот же объект, но как ответ сервера. Как мне теперь записать полученные от сервера обновлённые данные в массив `data`?

Да, я знаю `id`. Я могу сделать `find()`. Но так я не узнаю ключ массива, чтобы обратиться к объекту и заменить его. Как быть?

Пример запроса к серверу

```
async addService(sample, service_id) {
    let response = await axios.post('/sample-service', {
        'sample_id': sample.id,
        'service_id': service_id,
    });
    //Обработка ответа
},
```

Comment: Приложите фрагмент описанного кода, можно упрощено

Comment: какой код вам приложить, если я не могу этого сделать - обработать ответ. Вам код того, как я отправляю запрос показать? Ок

Comment: Меня интересует, как это делают вообще? Отправил. Получил ответ. И как теперь в массиве объектов заменить старые данные новыми?

Comment: Код нужен, потому что не понятно в чем загвоздка. Вы отправляете, запрос, получаете данные, даже меняете их и снова отправляете. Так в чем проблема использование вновь полученных данных? В каком месте кода возникает загвоздка?

Comment: Так, уточняю. Вы получаете объект с новыми данными по одному из элементов массива data, и задача обновить его в массиве?

Comment: Я ведь вроде бы описал всё. Имеется массив объектов. Например, список чего-нибудь, хоть игрушек - строк из БД. Я этот объект отображаю на странице в виде кнопок, форм и любого другого - это не важно. Пусть будут формы - так проще. Вот у меня три объекта. Три формы с данными этих объектов - имя, описание и другое. Я что-то меняю. Имя, например. Жму обновить. Данные формы летят на сервер. Обновляются на сервере данные. И мне приходит ответ - обновлённые данные от сервера. Теперь эти данные мне нужно всунуть обратно в массив объектов. Обновить. Но как? Я ведь не знаю ключ

Comment: я использую vue. Поэтому мне нужно только обновить данные в массиве, чтобы они отобразились везде, где используются.

Comment: vue это важное уточнение. Нужно еще реактивность сохранить

Comment: Сделайте цикл который будет проходить по data и найдет индекс нужного объекта, замените значение с помощью $set примерно так: this.data.$set(index, val)

Answer (score 1):

```
let data = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
];
async addService(sample, service_id) {
    let response = await axios.post('/sample-service', {
        'sample_id': sample.id,
        'service_id': service_id,
    });
    //Обработка ответа
    for (let i in data) {
        if (data[i].id === response.data.id) {
            data.splice(i, 1, response.data);
            break;
        }
    }
},
```